# Get depth from camera for each pixel

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, vtk, zbuffer

I have a mesh model and, using VTK, have rendered a view of it from a given camera position (x,y,z). I can save this to an RGB image (640x480) but I also want to save a depth map where each pixel stores the value of the depth from the camera.

I have tried using the `Zbuffer` values given by the render window by following [this example](http://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/ZBuffer). The problem is that the `Zbufer` only stores values in the range [0,1]. Instead I am trying to create synthetic range image, where I store the depth/distance of each pixel from the camera. Analogous to the image produced by the Kinect, I am trying to create one from a specific viewpoint of a mesh model.

**EDIT** - adding some code

My current code:

**Load the mesh**

```
string mesh_filename = "mesh.ply";
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPLYReader> mesh_reader = read_mesh_ply(mesh_filename);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
    mapper->SetInputConnection(mesh_reader->GetOutputPort());

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
    actor->SetMapper(mapper);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =  vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renderWindow->SetSize(640, 480);

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

    //Add the actors to the scene
    renderer->AddActor(actor);
    renderer->SetBackground(1, 1, 1);
```

**Create a camera and place it somewhere**

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> camera = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera>::New();

    renderer->SetActiveCamera(camera);
    camera->SetPosition(0,0,650);
    //Render and interact
    renderWindow->Render();
```

**Get result from the z buffer**

```
double b = renderer->GetZ(320, 240);
```

In this example, this gives 0.999995. As the values are between [0,1] I don't know how to interpret this, as you can see I have set the camera to be 650 units away on the z-axis so I assume the z distance at this pixel (which is on the object in the rendered RGB) should be near to 650.

Comment: Did you read this? http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/ZBuffer

Comment: @TomásBadan Hi, yes I have read this example. The problem is the zbufer only stores values in the range [0,1]. Instead I am trying to create synthetic range image, where I can get the depth/distance of each pixel from the camera. (editing question with this comment)

Comment: In openGL, z buffer are given in unitary values, where 1 means as far as possible and 0 means as near as possible. Are you sure that this buffer isn't unitary too?

Comment: @TomásBadan yes, that is the problem. Is there a way to convert this number to a "real" depth, i.e. in the units of the model?

Comment: As Tomas Badan say, 1 mean as far as possible and 0 as near as possible. If your camera near is 0 and far is 650, a z value of 1 mean 650. 
Real distance = zValue * (far-near)+near.
In your case: Real distance = zValue*650

Comment: @AdrianMaire I see, How can I find the actual near and far values for my camera/how can I set them?

Comment: When you set up openGL, you probably have a line like glFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far).
Or maybe you have used the glu equivalent? gluPerspective()?

Comment: @AdrianMaire I am not making these calls, all my code is shown above. I am using VTK, which is probably setting the clipping planes at some point

Comment: @Ali I have not knowleadge about VTK, but maybe following function may help you: vtkCamera::GetFrustumPlanes(double aspect, double planes[24])

Comment: The formula Adrian posted is only correct for orthographic projections. For perspective projections, the z-buffer isn't linear. My guess is that that's what the SetInputBufferTypeToZBuffer() method is supposed to take care of.

Comment: Hi, Did you actually managed to solve this ? I am at the same problem right now

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution other than rewriting the entire rendering pipeline ?

Answer (score 3):

This python snippet illustrates how to convert z buffer values to real distances. The non-linear mapping is defined as follows:

```
numerator = 2.0 * z_near * z_far
denominator = z_far + z_near - (2.0 * z_buffer_data_numpy - 1.0) * (z_far - z_near)
depth_buffer_data_numpy = numerator / denominator
```

Here, a full example:

```
import vtk
import numpy as np
from vtk.util import numpy_support
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

vtk_renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
vtk_render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
vtk_render_window.AddRenderer(vtk_renderer)
vtk_render_window_interactor = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
vtk_render_window_interactor.SetRenderWindow(vtk_render_window)
vtk_render_window_interactor.Initialize()

source = vtk.vtkCubeSource()
mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())
actor = vtk.vtkActor()
actor.SetMapper(mapper)
actor.RotateX(60.0)
actor.RotateY(-35.0)
vtk_renderer.AddActor(actor)

vtk_render_window.Render()
active_vtk_camera = vtk_renderer.GetActiveCamera()
z_near, z_far = active_vtk_camera.GetClippingRange()

z_buffer_data = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
width, height = vtk_render_window.GetSize()
vtk_render_window.GetZbufferData(
    0, 0, width - 1, height - 1, z_buffer_data)
z_buffer_data_numpy = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(z_buffer_data)
z_buffer_data_numpy = np.reshape(z_buffer_data_numpy, (-1, width))
z_buffer_data_numpy = np.flipud(z_buffer_data_numpy)  # flipping along the first axis (y)

numerator = 2.0 * z_near * z_far
denominator = z_far + z_near - (2.0 * z_buffer_data_numpy - 1.0) * (z_far - z_near)
depth_buffer_data_numpy = numerator / denominator
non_depth_data_value = np.nan
depth_buffer_data_numpy[z_buffer_data_numpy == 1.0] = non_depth_data_value

print(np.nanmin(depth_buffer_data_numpy))
print(np.nanmax(depth_buffer_data_numpy))

plt.imshow(np.asarray(depth_buffer_data_numpy))
plt.show()
```

Side note:
On my system, a few times the `imshow` command did not display anything. Re-running the script did solve that issue.

Sources:

[http://web.archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20130416194336/http://olivers.posterous.com/linear-depth-in-glsl-for-real) 
[open3d](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/blob/master/cpp/open3d/visualization/visualizer/VisualizerRender.cpp#L271)

Comment: Very nice, I would also suggest using the vtkWindowToImageFilter to get the ZBuffer instead of getting it directly from the render window